# How do I make a lottie animation take the full width and height of a flex container?

Tags: javascript, animation, lottie

I want to use this animation:
https://lottiefiles.com/18707-dragon-matrix-effect

I have adjusted the color to red in order to make it work with my project. It has downloaded as a 512x512 animation.

This is my JS code:

```
let lottieAnim = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: document.querySelector(".lottiecontainer"),
  renderer: "svg",
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  path: "/js/tAjGxx4stF.json",
  background: "transparent",

});
```

I've tried width parameters inside the lottieAnim var, in the css, but it will not scale past 512x512 pixels. How can I change this and make the lottie animation constantly fill the div it is placed inside in? The renderer is svg so it should be able to scale along just fine like a vector.

I've tried lottie documentation, tried googling, tried adding width/height parameters on both lottie and the css. Nothing worked.